# Why is there a different global navigation when you are at homepage or inside list/site content?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, global-navigation

Our global navigation has strange behavour.

When user is at startpage on a site the global navigation looks correct, but when same user navigates to a list or site content the global navigation looks different in a incorrect way. How is this even possible?

Startpage at the site:

[image]

When you are inside site content or inside a list.

[image]

**It seems to be a Microsoft issue, the issue occours if user is using the new interface. If you return to the old interface it works! ;)**

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots so we can understand what is happening?

Comment: @wjervis Take a look I added screenshots

Comment: What are the navigation settings?

Comment: @wjervis Structural navigation, show subsites and show pages is not checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Navigation setting (http://spsite/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx) uncheck the box saying to display pages in the top navigation.

If that doesn't solve your problem, I guess you're suffering from the same error MS has received in [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/14749329-managed-navigation-for-new-document-library-experi):

> "Currently the new document library experience does not support
>   Managed Navigation. It would be great to have this as currently using
>   the structured navigation seems buggy in the new experience.
>   Specifically, it ignores the "hidden" attribute of structured
>   navigation which can make for some large menus. We love the new
>   experience and are hoping to train users up and roll it out however we
>   need to get navigation right before we can do this."

Comment: http://imgur.com/p6EgIr4 if you check this link you can see our navigation settings. And I guess it looks just like the way you mentioned. It have not solved the  problem. So basicly its a MS bug?

Comment: @Rohander true ;(

Comment: The issue seems to be new the interface. If you return to classic interface it works! ;)